# Move shipping options outside WooCommerce checkout order review

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

On woocommerce checkout, I want to move the shipping options outside of woocommerce_order_review which I can do no problem but I need it to update when the address is updated - WC_AJAX::update_order_review()

I can get this working by editing the public static function update_order_review() in woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php but I don't want to be editing the core files.

Is there a way to change this function in my themes function file? All I want to do is add in a new fragment

```
  ob_start();
  woocommerce_checkout_shipping_options();
  $woocommerce_checkout_shipping_options = ob_get_clean();
```

and add

```
'.woocommerce-checkout-shipping-table' => $woocommerce_checkout_shipping_options,
```

into the  woocommerce_update_order_review_fragments array.

I already have the template function in my themes functions.php

```
function woocommerce_checkout_shipping_options( ) {
        wc_get_template(
            'checkout/shipping-options.php',
            array(
                'checkout' => WC()->checkout(),
            )
        );
    }
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping_option', 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping_options', 10 );
```

I cannot see a way of editing the update_order_review function without editing the core files?

Answer (score 5):

Never edit WooCommerce core files for many reasons. There is always a way to get things done.

To make the changes that you want is much more easy than you think, and can be done as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_order_review_fragments', 'filter_update_order_review_fragments' );
function filter_update_order_review_fragments( $fragments ){
    ob_start();
    woocommerce_checkout_shipping_options();
    $fragments['.woocommerce-checkout-shipping-table'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.